# How to transfer parameters in th:href in spring boot Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

These are my simple Thymeleaf table HTML file and Spring MVC controller codes. First below is my table image.

[image]

I try to make some html codes to transfer the post id value to view codes when the 'Edit' or 'Delete' link are clicked, but I have no idea how to do. These are my Spring MVC Controller codes and view.html codes.

```
@Controller
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @RequestMapping("/posts/view/{id}")
    public String view(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        Post post = postService.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("post", post);

        return "posts/view";
    }
```

And,

```
<table id="blogTable" border="1" width ="1000" height="400" align = "center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Post ID</th>
                <th>Post Title</th>
                <th>Post Content</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="post : ${posts}">
            <td th:text="${post.id}">Post ID</td>    
            <td th:text="${post.title}">Post Title</td>
            <td th:text="${post.body}">Post Content</td>
            <td th:text="${post.date}">Date</td>
            <!--  <td th:text="${post.auther.userName()}">Author</td> -->
            <td>
                <a href="posts/view.html" th:href="@{posts/view/post.id}">Edit</a><br/>  ==> How to transfer the post.id parameter to th:href?
                <a href="posts/view.html" th:href="@{posts/view/post.id}">Delete</a>  ==> How to transfer the post.id parameter to th:href?
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

I am a beginner in HTML and Spring. How can I put post.id value into view mvc controller through `th:href` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can something try like following:

```
<a href="posts/view.html" th:href="@{/posts/view/__${post.id}__}">Edit</a><br/>
<a href="posts/view.html" th:href="@{/posts/view/__${post.id}__}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry for my mistake

Comment: Just click on down arrow.

Answer (score 6):

Use th:href like described in the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls)

> - th:href is an attribute modifier attribute: once processed, it will compute the link URL to be used and set the href attribute of the  tag to this URL.
> - We are allowed to use expressions for URL parameters (as you can see in orderId=${o.id}). The required URL-encoding operations will also be automatically performed.
> - If several parameters are needed, these will be separated by commas like @{/order/process(execId=${execId},execType='FAST')}
> - Variable templates are also allowed in URL paths, like @{/order/{orderId}/details(orderId=${orderId})}

For example (notice the `th:href` and the parameter `postId` that receives the value from your variable `post`):

```
<td>
     <a href="posts/view.html" th:href="@{posts/view/{postId}(postId=${post.id})}">Edit</a><br/>  ==> How to transfer the post.id parameter to th:href?
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add parameters in parentheses:

`<a th:href="@{/index(param1='value1',param2='value2')}">`

Thymeleaf evaluates the above to:

`<a href="/index?param1=value1,m2=value2">`

For example, suppose we set default value to two parameters; name="Dracula" and age = 25.

`<a th:href=@{/person(name=${name},age=${age})}></a>`

`<a href="/person?name='Dracula',age='25'"></a>`

Answer (score 1):

I used in this format and work fine.

```
<a th:href="@{${urlBase} + '/#!/pedido' + ${other.value}" target="_blank">Link</a>
```